# Length of array self decreases

Tags: java, android

I have following code

```
    Log.i("fulldatestr", fullDateString);
    String[] parts = fullDateString.split("-");
    for(String str : parts)
    {
        Log.i("count", Integer.toString(parts.length));
        Log.i("str", str);
    }
    Log.i("0 is ", parts[0]);
    dayNumOfMonth = parts[2]; // ERROR LINE
```

It causes error `ArrayOutOfBoundsException`. Somehow length goes from `3` to `1`. Here is Log output.

```
05-07 19:15:29.273: I/fulldatestr(30925): 2015-04-01
05-07 19:15:29.273: I/count(30925): 3
05-07 19:15:29.273: I/str(30925): 2015
05-07 19:15:29.273: I/count(30925): 3
05-07 19:15:29.273: I/str(30925): 04
05-07 19:15:29.273: I/count(30925): 3
05-07 19:15:29.273: I/str(30925): 01
05-07 19:15:29.273: I/0 is(30925): 2015
05-07 19:15:29.283: I/count(30925): 1
05-07 19:15:29.283: W/System.err(30925): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=2
```

As you can see it splits fine, parses fine and then boom length is 1. Help me. Note: this code worked fine before.

Comment: Your log output doesn't seem to match the code exactly. The second to last line of log output prints the count, but there is no Log statement in the code that prints the count after the "0 is" log statement. Did you remove any code before posting it?

Comment: @Bron , NO! And this is the second wierd thing

Comment: @Faceles do not you think it is gonna be helpful to post up your fullDateString content?

Comment: @KickButtowski first line is Log of fullDateString

Comment: @Faceles but what it has?

Comment: @KickButtowski 2015-04-01

Comment: Is Log a custom-built logging class?

Comment: @Bron Android native (android.util.Log)

Comment: @Faceles the only issue that I can see is there is not type of for dayNumOfMonth? ( I chose type String for dayNumOfMonth) but beside when I change log to System.out. in my code, I can see an outcome which I do not know if it is what you are looking for?count 3
str 2015
count 3
str 04
count 3
str 01
0 is 2015
II 01

Comment: ok, i've run this code, and it's fine, maybe some threads using your string while you're logging?

Comment: @NikMyers string is local to method, how can it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLUTION FOUND. Changed `Log` to `System.Out.println` and I saw That Log doesn't print empty string and the problem is in another `fullDateString` that was badly parsed from web. Thank you all for help.

Answer (score 1):

Your snippet works fine.

The output of your log is not compatible with the procedural flow of your code: this means your are probably experiencing some concurrency-related problem (e.g. this can happen if some of your vars are declared as fields). Also take a look at the execution time: you move from *19:15:29.273* to *19:15:29.283* just before the crash.

Comment: Also thought about some thread problems, but String[] parts is local to method (constructor) jsut like in code I posted. So, how can it be affected by other threads if it is local?

Comment: @Faceles we need the whole code in order to figure out the specific problem